# cin in c++ does not read visual studio command line arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to get started on using visual studio 2022 for c++.

SO I created the most basic windows console application, and added this simple sample code:

#include

```
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string firstName;

    std::cin >> firstName; // get user input from the keyboard
    std::cout << "Your name is: " << firstName;
}
```

And then I went to `properties> Configuration properties> Debugging` and then in "command arguments" i filled in "dingdong".

I then run the program, and nothing happens. It just hangs and waits for input.
If I do type something in the started terminal, then it takes the input and runs the program.

Why does it not take the command line argument I have put in?

Comment: No, `std::cin` doesn't do that. Command line arguments are passed through the `argc` and `argv` arguments of your `main()` function. But you even didn't specify these.

Comment: *"If I do type something in the started terminal, then it takes the input and runs the program."*. This is wrong enough to warrant comment. The program runs. The program waits for input using `cin`, and continues when `cin` returns (with input or error). What I mean, is, it does not first take the input and then run the program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read arguments from command line, it happens via `main` parameters. `argc` tells numbers of arguments, including program name, which is `argv[0]`. Here we want first name at `argv[1]`, then.

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string firstName;
    if (argc >= 2) { // test that argv[1] is valid
        firstName = argv[1]; // take first name from command line
        // ignore any additional arguments
    } else {
        // no command line arguments given, read first name from cin
        std::cin >> firstName; // get user input from the keyboard
        // should add check for cin error
    }

    std::cout << "Your name is: " << firstName;
}
```